# Sum mysql results for each pair

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sum, subquery

Table locations :

```
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| Id | Old Value | New Value |        Date         |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 | Home      | Work      | 2016-11-01 09:00:00 |
|  2 | Work      | Home      | 2016-11-01 09:25:00 |
|  3 | Home      | Work      | 2016-11-01 09:44:59 |
|  4 | Work      | Home      | 2016-11-01 10:11:50 |
|  5 | Home      | Work      | 2016-11-01 10:25:30 |
|  6 | Work      | Home      | 2016-11-01 11:01:15 |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
```

My Query :

```
    SELECT loc1.*,loc2.date AS loc2_date, SUM(CAST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND,loc1.date,loc2.date)/1000000 AS DECIMAL(20))) AS time_diff
FROM locations AS loc1
        LEFT JOIN locations AS loc2 ON loc1.old_value=loc2.new_value AND loc2.id > loc1.id
        WHERE old_value="Home"
```

My Query Result :

```
Id: 1
Old Value: Home
New Value: Work
Date: 2016-11-01 09:00:00
Loc2_date: 2016-11-01 09:25:00
Time_fidd: 1500

Id: 1
Old Value: Home
New Value: Work
Date: 2016-11-01 09:00:00
Loc2_date: 2016-11-01 10:11:50
Time_diff: 4310

Id: 1
Old Value: Home
New Value: Work
Date: 2016-11-01 09:00:00
Loc2_date: 2016-11-01 11:01:15
Time_diff: 7275

Id: 3
Old Value: Home
New Value: Work
Date: 2016-11-01 09:44:59
Loc2_date: 2016-11-01 10:11:50
Time_diff: 1611

Id: 3
Old Value: Home
New Value: Work
Date: 2016-11-01 09:44:59
Loc2_date: 2016-11-01 11:01:15
Time_diff: 4576

Id: 5
Old Value: Home
New Value: Work
Date: 2016-11-01 10:25:30
Loc2_date: 2016-11-01 11:01:15
Time_diff: 2145
```

I wanna sum the date to see all the seconds I was at work. If I group by Id will show exactly what I need but when I sum the difference between `loc1.date` and `loc2.date` the query will skip group by and keep returning all the rows. Please help.

What I need from my query :

```
Id: 1
Old Value: Home
New Value: Work
Date: 2016-11-01 09:00:00
Loc2_date: 2016-11-01 09:25:00
Time_fidd: 1500

Id: 3
Old Value: Home
New Value: Work
Date: 2016-11-01 09:44:59
Loc2_date: 2016-11-01 10:11:50
Time_diff: 1611

Id: 5
Old Value: Home
New Value: Work
Date: 2016-11-01 10:25:30
Loc2_date: 2016-11-01 11:01:15
Time_diff: 2145
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Try this.

```
SELECT tablea.id, tablea.`Old_value`, tablea.`New_value`, tablea.`Date`, tablea.`Date` Loc2_date, SUM(tablea.time_diff) AS time_diff 
FROM 
(
    SELECT loc1.`id`, loc1.`Old_value`, loc1.`New_value`, loc1.`Date`, loc2.`Date` Loc2_date, CAST(ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, loc2.date, loc1.date)/1000000) AS DECIMAL(20)) time_diff
    FROM locations loc1 INNER JOIN locations loc2
    ON loc1.`Old_value`=loc2.`New_value` AND loc2.`id`>loc1.`id`
    WHERE loc1.`Old_value`="Home"
    GROUP BY loc1.`id`
) tablea
```

**Example:**

```
SELECT tableb.*
FROM
(
    SELECT tablea.id, tablea.`Old_value`, tablea.`New_value`, tablea.`Date`, tablea.`Date` Loc2_date, SUM(tablea.time_diff) AS time_diff 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT loc1.`id`, loc1.`Old_value`, loc1.`New_value`, loc1.`Date`, loc2.`Date` Loc2_date, CAST(ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, loc2.date, loc1.date)/1000000) AS DECIMAL(20)) time_diff
        FROM locations loc1 INNER JOIN locations loc2
        ON loc1.`Old_value`=loc2.`New_value` AND loc2.`id`>loc1.`id`
        WHERE loc1.`Old_value`="Home"
        GROUP BY loc1.`id`
    ) tablea    
) tableb
```

**Old Answer.**

You can try **[group_by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)** for this. Add `GROUP BY loc1.id` after `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT loc1.*,loc2.date AS loc2_date, SUM(CAST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND,loc1.date,loc2.date)/1000000 AS DECIMAL(20)))
FROM locations AS loc1
LEFT JOIN locations AS loc2 ON loc1.old_value=loc2.new_value AND loc2.id > loc1.id
WHERE old_value="Home"
GROUP BY loc1.id
```

Comment: It won't work, mysql will return all the combinations and will sum all :( I've tried will left join, inner join, and subquery

Comment: Still won't work, i need SUM(CAST(ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, loc2.date, loc1.date)/1000000) AS DECIMAL(20))). Mysql need to return only one row with SUM. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Can't use FROM subquery because this query will be a subquery.

Comment: @GrempelsGabriel You can use it in subquery too. There should be no problem. See example by the way.